# Identify lines and put a > before them

Tags: php

Let's say I had this text:

```
Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum. 

Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, in viverra nulla condimentum eu. 
Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, malesuada lacus. 

Integer cursus malesuada consectetur. 
Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue. 
Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat. 
Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.
```

And wanted to put a > before every line, like so:

```
> Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum. 
>
> Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, in viverra nulla condimentum eu. 
> Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, malesuada lacus. 
>
> Integer cursus malesuada consectetur. 
> Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue. 
> Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat. 
> Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.
```

What function should I look into/how would i do?

Comment: Have you tried anything?  What research/effort have you put into this so far?  Where's the input text coming from?  Have you figured out how to read it?

Comment: Tack one on the start, then replace each "\n" with "\n>"?

Comment: This could work: `implode("\n", array_map(function($x) { return '> '.$x; }, explode("\n", $your_text)));` or `'> '.str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $your_text);`

Comment: "Lines" are "pieces of text delimited by an end-of-line sequence, usually the newline character" (which is `"\n"` as a PHP string). So, look into functions that manipulate strings and/or replace parts of them with something else: `explode`, `str_replace`, `preg_replace`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use str_replace and rtrim for this

```
 $str = rtrim("> ".str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $str), ">\n");
```

omit rtrim if you want to retain any trailing `>`'s

**TEST**

```
<?php
$str = 'Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum.

Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, in viverra nulla condimentum eu.
Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, malesuada lacus.

Integer cursus malesuada consectetur.
Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue.
Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat.
Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.';

 $str = rtrim(">".str_replace("\n", "\n> ", $str), ">\n");

 echo $str;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum.
> 
> Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, in viverra nulla condimentum eu.
> Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, malesuada lacus.
> 
> Integer cursus malesuada consectetur.
> Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue.
> Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat.
> Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.
```

Comment: Might want to add a space after the first ">" for balance

Comment: @StephenTG just noticed that... thanks

Comment: And now in the results...

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = 'Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum.

Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, in viverra nulla condimentum eu.
Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, malesuada lacus.

Integer cursus malesuada consectetur.
Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue.
Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat.
Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.';

$str = ">" . $str;
$str = preg_replace("/\n/", "\n>",$str);
print $str;
```

Prints:

```
>Vivamus ullamcorper adipiscing bibendum.
>
>Etiam faucibus facilisis tortor, in viverra nulla condimentum eu.
>Vivamus eu tellus adipiscing, molestie nisi vel, malesuada lacus.
>
>Integer cursus malesuada consectetur.
>Curabitur tellus mi, tristique vel urna et, auctor tincidunt augue.
>Cras semper, nisl sodales viverra volutpat.
>Phasellus feugiat quam nec orci accumsan gravida ut vitae risus.
```

Comment: or use `$str = ">".implode("\n>", explode("\n", $str));`

Comment: @StephenTG True, but I think, that regexp will work faster, then explode/implode - can you measure the time?

Comment: Using microtime, I'm getting 2.2172927856445E-5 microseconds for mine and 0.00025105476379395 for yours

Comment: And orangepill's takes ~2/3 the time mine does

Comment: @StephenTG Yours is 10 times faster on your machine. On my machine the results are: 0.012854 mine, 0.00017 - yours. Yours is 75,6 times faster, then mine.

Comment: @StephenTG Orangepills variant is the current winner with 0.00011

Comment: The PHP doc's for str_replace [allude to how slow `preg_replace()` is](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) -  `If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of preg_replace().`